I want to execute a sub flow for every user login in keycloak authentication flow
I have created a custom auth flow in keycloak, I want to execute a sub flow for every user login.
Find the below expected behavior,
For example I have 3 conditional Sub flows and 1 Required Sub Flow in my Auth flow. from the 3 conditions it'll execute atleast once and after that required sub should get executed.
But the issue is after the conditional flow the required flow is not getting executed. I'm attaching the screen shot of Auth flow from my Keycloak UI.

In the above Image you can see there 3 conditional flows and a Required flow, here the conditional flows are getting executed properly, but after that the last required flow is not executing. Inside all Sub flows I have added some custom authentication steps for my own authentication purpose.
Do I need to change any setting to make it work?
